# fw_printenv and fw_setenv output 'Environmet WRONG, copy 0' on Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, u-boot, raspberry-pi4

**Summary**

I want to use `fw_printenv` and `fw_setenv` on Raspberry Pi 4(RPi4) with Ubuntu 20.04 to print and set a environment value for U-Boot. When runs those commands, then I can see following errors on the UART console:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fw_printenv
Environment WRONG, copy 0
Cannot read environment, using default
Cannot read default environment from file

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fw_setenv asdf 123
Environment WRONG, copy 0
Cannot read environment, using default
Cannot read default environment from file
```

Does anyone know how to fix the problem?

**What I've tried**

First I created a SD card with Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit (Released: 2021-08-26) using the official Raspberry Pi Imager. Then I run it on RPi4 and updated the software by `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`.

After updating, I realized that `uboot.env` does not exist at `/boot/firmware`, so I set a test environment value on U-Boot something like:

```
U-Boot> setenv asdf 123
U-Boot> saveenv
Saving Environment to FAT... OK
U-Boot> printenv
arch=arm
asdf=123
...
```

Then `uboot.env` has been created at `/boot/firmware`. It could be confirmed on Ubuntu:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/boot/firmware$ ls -l uboot.env
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 131072 Jan  1  1980 uboot.env
```

In addition, I could not find a configuration file for the `fw_printenv` at `/etc/fw_env.config`, so I created it:

```
/boot/firmware/uboot.env 0x0000 0x20000
```

Finally I run the `fw_printenv` and `fw_setenv` but got the errors as I mentioned earlier. On the other hand, `uboot.env` is accessible simply running `less` or `cat`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/boot/firmware$ less uboot.env
"uboot.env" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
<BA><9C>^Sf^Aarch=arm^@asdf=123^@ ...
```

**Version Info**

On U-Boot:

```
U-Boot> version
U-Boot 2021.01+dfsg-3ubuntu0~20.04.3 (Jul 30 2021 - 14:38:17 +0000)

gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34
```

On Ubuntu:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-1044-raspi #48-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 9 15:24:01 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ fw_setenv -V
0.2
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ fw_printenv -V
0.2
```

Comment: The default size of the environment size for the Raspberry Pi 4 is 0x4000 (not 0x20000). I created https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/u-boot/+bug/1946354.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As ls command output said the size the uboot.env is 131072 bytes, so I thought that way. Just in case, I changed the size in fw_env.config to 0x4000 and tried to run the command again, but the result was the same.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.    Anything further?